# Trigger Jenkins job remotely from Azure Functions / Azure VM

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-functions

Am pretty new with Jenkins and just simply can't get this to work. I have been browsing the net for an answer but have not found an answer, or might not have understood what I should do.

I have Jobs in Jenkins that are currently scheduled (Python scripts). But one of these needs to be converted to be triggered remotely via URL. This I have been able to achieve and everything works fine when I am using the URL to trigger the Job from within our network at the office (Python, CMD, Browser, Postman etc).

However, when using this same URL to trigger the Job from Azure Functions or Azure VM, the Job is not being triggered (different IP - I believe this has to be the issue). I have been trying to open up the port 8080 on the machine currently running our Jenkins server by altering the Firewall settings, but regardless the HTTP POST isn't coming through. Triggering the Job from Azure Functions would be the goal.

Is there something obvious I am missing here in regards to Jenkins or is it just simply the fact that our Firewall is blocking the connection as we need to use VPN to connect into our local network from the outside. We only have set up Jenkins on one computer (a computer running within our local network) and have not introduced any slave nodes.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you just need to call the url, can you just create a VM somewhere in azure (or just use Azure Cloud Shell) and verify that the url responds with something at least?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We have Azure VM running and the URL doesn't respond when called from there (tried browser, postman, python script etc). Same goes for the Azure Functions running in our App Service. But when calling the URL from any other computer within our local IP it works like a charm.

Comment: yeah, so I would think its firewall\connectivity related

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep battling with the firewall then. Just wasn't sure if I missed something in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed does sound like a Firewall problem. There are quite a few ways to achieve such on-premise implementations in Azure without opening up your network to the outside.

Starting with the simplest approach

---

### A. **Logic Apps**

[Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/logic-apps/) because of its support for the [On-Premises Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection) which allows it to access data from on-premises systems.

This has a couple of components to it

1. **Custom Connector**
   You would have to [create a custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank) which can connect via on-premises data gateway and have one action defined which can call your Jenkins machine
2. **Setup On-Premise Data Gateway**
   You would have to [setup the on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) on your local network so that it has access to your Jenkins master (can be on the same host as the Jenkins master too)
3. **Create a Logic App**
   This is the easy part where you use a Logic App instead of Function App. You can create a simple [HTTP triggered Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-http-trigger) which uses the Custom Connector that you created to trigger the Jenkins job

---

### B. **Azure Automation**

[Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/automation/) has a similar feature wherein you can deploy a [Hybrid Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) in your on-premises network and schedule jobs into that worker.

You could deploy either of the following workers based on your requirement

1. [Windows Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-windows-hrw-install)
2. [Linux Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-linux-hrw-install)

The runbook that you would write could be either in [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell) or [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-python2) and its purpose would be to just call the Jenkins API to start the job.

With all this in place, you would just have to [start the runbook on the hybrid worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hrw-run-runbooks).

You could also [start a runbook from a webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) as well.

---

### C. **Connect your On-Premise network to Azure**

This is more of a networking solution wherein you connect your on-premise network to an Azure VNET, allowing any resources in that VNET to access your on-premise systems.

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/)

1. [VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/vpn)
2. [Express Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/expressroute)

I won't go deep on how these are setup here. You can refer the documentation for detailed instructions on setting things up.

Once setup, you could either

- **Expose Jenkins**
  For this you could simple just open a port on your VNET's NSG but this really isn't recommended I guess, since you might as well just expose it on your on-premises network directly instead.

  The preferred way would be to setup and use an [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) which is basically a reverse proxy.
- **Deploy your Function or Logic App into the VNET**
  If you don't want to expose your Jenkins endpoint to the outside, you could deploy either

  - [Function App into App Service Environment (ASE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase#web-jobs-functions-and-the-ilb-ase)
  - [Logic App into Integration Service Environment (ISE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview)

  > In both of these scenarios, you could directly call the Jenkins endpoint using the IP where its hosted (the on-premise IP itself)