# Call Jenkins API from Azure logic APP in order to trigger a job

Tags: azure, api, jenkins, logic

I have created jenkins job and I want to trigger it by calling jenkins api from azure logic app.

I am using api: 
  http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build?token=TokenName

does anyone know how to set it in azure to call this api properly?

NOw i have set it like that(of course with replaced api data):

METHOD: POST
URI: http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build?token=TokenName

but i receive error 308:

```
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.15.8.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

from my pc and from the network where the azure is placed this api can be called without any problem ( i use python script or curl)

Does anyone have any clue how to set it up in azure portal?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

308 (Permanent redirect) indicates that the target resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities, ought to automatically relink references to the effective request URI to one or more of the new references sent by the server, where possible.

I believe you would have to [setup On-Premise Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) on your local network so that it has access to your Jenkins environment.

References:

- [Trigger Jenkins job remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236029/trigger-jenkins-job-remotely-from-azure-functions-azure-vm)
- [Application Gateway redirect overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview)
- [URL redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect)